# Edit using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

This is my edit code :

```
    Dim nom As String = NomBox.Text
    Dim prenom As String = PrenomBox.Text
    Dim email As String = EmailBox.Text
    Dim dn As String = DnBox.Text
    Dim da As String = DaBox.Text
    Dim tel As String = TelBox.Text

    Dim SQL As String
    Dim sqlparams() As SqlParameter
    If Page.IsPostBack Then
        SQL = " UPDATE ASSMS__Members SET First_Name=@1,Last_Name=@2,Birth_Date=@3,Email=@4,Mobile_1=@5,Membership_Date=@6 WHERE ID_=@7"
        sqlparams = {
        New SqlParameter("@1", SqlDbType.Text, 200),
        New SqlParameter("@2", SqlDbType.Text, 100000),
        New SqlParameter("@3", SqlDbType.Date),
        New SqlParameter("@4", SqlDbType.Text, 100000),
        New SqlParameter("@5", SqlDbType.Text, 100000),
        New SqlParameter("@6", SqlDbType.Date),
       New SqlParameter("@7", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier)
   }
        sqlparams(0).Value = NomBox.Text
        sqlparams(1).Value = PrenomBox.Text
        sqlparams(2).Value = EmailBox.Text
        sqlparams(3).Value = DnBox.Text
        sqlparams(4).Value = DaBox.Text
        sqlparams(5).Value = TelBox.Text
        sqlparams(6).Value = Guid.Parse(Request.Params("ID_"))
        _Conn.Connection_On()
        _Conn.Execute_Sql_Prepare(SQL, "NonQuery", sqlparams)
        _Conn.Connection_Off()
        Response.Redirect("./ListeMembres.aspx")

    End If
```

I have always an error:

> La chaîne n'a pas été reconnue comme DateTime valide. Il existe un mot inconnu commençant à l'index 0.

> The channel has not been recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.

How to fix it please?

Comment: `sqlparams(2).Value = EmailBox.Text` <-- I would guess that `EmailBox` contains a DateTime value, at least judging by the name.

Comment: It looks like you switched first name and last name. Isn't PrenomBox the first name?

Comment: From the docs "IMPORTANT! ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I know storage is cheap but several of the string fields seem way too large.

Comment: Parameter at index 2 is `New SqlParameter("@3", SqlDbType.Date)` but you are assigning an email address to it. Don't number the parameters; give them real names and you won't get so mixed up.

Comment: This is an English-only web site. If you are using a different language version of VS then it is your responsibility to translate error messages, etc. *"The channel has not been recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting on index 0"*.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fine example of why you should ALWAYS use descriptive names. Your parameters are quite all over the place. I would suggest clarifying and simplifying this:

```vb
SQL = " UPDATE ASSMS__Members SET First_Name=@1,Last_Name=@2,Birth_Date=@3,Email=@4,Mobile_1=@5,Membership_Date=@6 WHERE ID_=@7"
sqlparams = {
New SqlParameter("@1", SqlDbType.Text, 200),
New SqlParameter("@2", SqlDbType.Text, 100000),
New SqlParameter("@3", SqlDbType.Date),
New SqlParameter("@4", SqlDbType.Text, 100000),
New SqlParameter("@5", SqlDbType.Text, 100000),
New SqlParameter("@6", SqlDbType.Date),
New SqlParameter("@7", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier)
}
sqlparams(0).Value = NomBox.Text
sqlparams(1).Value = PrenomBox.Text
sqlparams(2).Value = EmailBox.Text
sqlparams(3).Value = DnBox.Text
sqlparams(4).Value = DaBox.Text
sqlparams(5).Value = TelBox.Text
sqlparams(6).Value = Guid.Parse(Request.Params("ID_"))
```

to this:

```vb
SQL = "UPDATE ASSMS__Members
       SET First_Name = @First_Name,
           Last_Name = @Last_Name,
           Birth_Date = @Birth_Date,
           Email = @Email,
           Mobile_1 = @Mobile_1,
           Membership_Date = @Membership_Date
       WHERE ID_ = @ID_"
sqlparams = {New SqlParameter("@First_Name", SqlDbType.Text, 200) With {.Value = PrenomBox.Text},
             New SqlParameter("@Last_Name", SqlDbType.Text, 100000) With {.Value = NomBox.Text},
             New SqlParameter("@Birth_Date", SqlDbType.Date) With {.Value = CDate(DnBox.Text)},
             New SqlParameter("@Email", SqlDbType.Text, 100000) With {.Value = EmailBox.Text},
             New SqlParameter("@Mobile_1", SqlDbType.Text, 100000) With {.Value = TelBox.Text},
             New SqlParameter("@Membership_Date", SqlDbType.Date) With {.Value = CDate(DaBox.Text)},
             New SqlParameter("@ID_", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier) With {.Value = Guid.Parse(Request.Params("ID_"))}}
```

I'm not sure whether I got your dates the right way around because you have used terrible names for them too but you can switch them if appropriate. I have also assumed that their contents has already been validated.

Answer (score 0):

I have separated the user interface code and the database code. Validation of the user input happens in the UI code and the validated code is sent to the database code.

Your connection should be local to the method where it is used so it can be closed and disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks handle this for you even if there is an error.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    If Page.IsPostBack Then
        'Validate user input
        Dim Dn As Date
        If Not Date.TryParse(DnBox.Text, Dn) Then
            'Alert the user and allow user to correct input
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim Da As Date
        If Not Date.TryParse(DaBox.Text, Da) Then
            'Alert the user and allow user to correct input
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Try
            UpdateDatabase(PrenomBox.Text, NomBox.Text, EmailBox.Text, Dn, Da, TelBox.Text, Guid.Parse(Request.Params("ID_")))
        Catch ex As Exception
            'Alert the user of Update Failure
            Exit Sub
        End Try
        Response.Redirect("./ListeMembres.aspx")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateDatabase(FirstName As String, LastName As String, Email As String, Dn As Date, Da As Date, Tel As String, ID As Guid)
    Dim SQL As String = "UPDATE ASSMS__Members SET 
                        First_Name = @FirstName, 
                        Last_Name = @LastName, 
                        Birth_Date = @DOB, 
                        Email = @Email, 
                        Mobile_1 = @Mobile, 
                        Membership_Date = @MemberDate 
                        WHERE ID_ = @ID;"
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As New SqlCommand(SQL, cn)
        With cmd.Parameters
            .Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.Text, 200).Value = FirstName
            .Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.Text, 100000).Value = LastName
            .Add("@DOB", SqlDbType.Date).Value = Da
            .Add("@Email", SqlDbType.Text, 100000).Value = Email
            .Add("@Mobile", SqlDbType.Text, 100000).Value = Tel
            .Add("@MemberDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = Dn
            .Add("@ID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = ID
        End With
        cn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```